# How to apt-get upgrade only one package in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, apt

Want to upgrade only a single apt package , without any changes to other auto system packages.
Example package for `Jenkins`

Answer (score 6):

To upgrade a single process in Ubuntu

**Update: apt update**

First update the apt packages to fetch latest versions

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

**Upgrade only single package:**

In general, replace the package name to your target package

```
$ sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install <package>
```

**Example:**

**Upgrade only Jenkins:**

Use the following commands

```
$ sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install jenkins
```

And then restart the Jenkins server using command

```
$ sudo systemctl restart jenkins.service
```